# Ubuntu 22.04 freezes when opening Activities view after waking up from suspend/sleep

Tags: nvidia, suspend, 22.04, wayland, activities-overview

Please Help >> Each time I lock the computer and it goes to sleep, when I wake it up and press the *Super* key to show the *Activities Overview* view, it freezes on me (Only the Activities application), I'm not able to use most of the screen. The menus are accessible and I can log out and then log back in. However, it's super annoying... can anyone give me a hint as to what I can do to fix it.

Also, I don't know if it's related but I'm not able to use the Extensions Manager GUI (I worked around this by installing it from Flatpak)

I'm using **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 64-Bit** on a **Dell G3 3500** Procesor: **Intel® Core™ i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz × 12** and Graphics: **NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 / NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti/PCIe/SSE2** 
**GNOME 42.4** and **Wayland Windowing System** Im also using **NVIDIA 515 Proprietary** drivers

Comment: "Sleep" unfortunately does not always work well, especially if you have proprietary hardware with proprietary drivers on board like your nvidia graphics card. Disabling the sleep function may be you only workaround.

Comment: got it, is there a way to "kill" the Activities Overview when it's 'frozen' or maybe restart it somehow?